# Populating Material UI List with List Items by fetching from database outputting empty list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mapping, web3js

I want to call my database API to information regarding a users public_address(metamask), first_name and last_name.

Once I have this data (I call an api), I then use the mapping function in a list and then generate ListButtonItems for each element in my list.

**What I have done**

My API call is working perfectly fine, but the issue is my result array isn't populating, for example, when I retrieve my response (response is successfully fetched from the API), I add all the contents from my response to an array variable, this array always however appear s empty (I think this is due to the async nature of axios)

**Code**

```
import {Box, Button, Grid, List, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemText} from "@mui/material"
import {useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

 function RequestApproval() {

    let resultArray = [];

    const result =  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/all-user-addresses").then((response) => {
     resultArray.concat(response.data.result);

    })

     const listItems = resultArray.map((items) => <ListItemButton component="a" onClick={() => alert("Clicked")}>
         <ListItemText primary={items.first_name}/>
     </ListItemButton>)

     console.log(resultArray) //This appears as empty

    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh'}}>
            <Box style={{borderRadius: '16px', backgroundColor: '#6ea6be'}}>
                <List sx={{width: '600px', maxWidth: '1000px'}}>
                    {listItems}
                </List>
            </Box>
        </div>

    );
}

export default RequestApproval;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your function as `async function RequestApproval()`.
Await for response from get request -> `const result =  await axios.get(...)...`.
console.log(response.data) to see what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SWR, as it seems to be the recommended approach. At least in the Next.js community.

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = async (url: string) =>
  await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
        
    const {
        data: result,
        isLoading,
        error,
        mutate,
      } = useSWR(`http://localhost:3001/all-user-addresses`, fetcher, { suspense: true });

if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>;

 result.forEach((item }) => {
...;
```

});